# UserDefaults Auto-Login isn't Working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, persistence, nsuserdefaults

So when the user first opens my app they will see a view with a button to proceed with logging in or registering. In my Login view, I have a button handler (attached via action) which is called when a user presses a login button. Despite me using UserDefaults to store logged in state, my app does not go straight to my Dashboard view automatically. Any ideas why?

```
// Firebase auth in doLogin action (Login VC)

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: un, password: pw)
{
    (resp, err) in if (err == nil && resp != nil)
    {
        if (resp!.user.isEmailVerified)
        {

            // segue from Login VC to Dashboard VC will be exectuted

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loggedin", sender: nil)


            // store the logged in state as true for the future

            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "loggedin")

            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Main view controller to determine if it should proceed directly to dashboard.

```
func loggedIn() -> Bool {

    // determine if the user is still logged into the app

    return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "loggedin")

}


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()


    if (loggedIn())
    {

        // logged in, return to the dashboard view controller

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "persisted", sender: nil)

    }

}
```

I've tried using print statements and either the `loggedIn` function isn't being executed for whatever reason or the console is just too flooded with Firebase debug log statements to even see these.

Comment: To clarify, I double click the simulator button and close the app. Then I attempt to open it again. Instead of going straight to the dashboard, it stays on the main view.

Comment: There has to be an error somewhere else. How does your `AppDelegate` code look like? What is your storyboard setup?

Comment: I haven't changed my app delegate at all other than to configure the Firebase app and initialize a Cocoa pod called `IQKeyboardManager`

Comment: [Here](https://ibb.co/iYVWrd) is my storyboard. Back buttons are handled via actions in the code which is why you don't see them there.

Comment: And your `loggedIn` function is not called at all?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be called when I use print statements. Also tried calling a segue in the helper, and it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Uff. That sounds weird. Is it possible for you to share the project temporarily?

Comment: I can't really send you it but TeamViewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174269/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-malik-brahimi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embed your main view controller inside a `UINavigationController` to make the `persisted` segue work.